# Qt: Are non-rectangular QWidgets allowed to overlap?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qgraphicsitem

If I have multiple non-rectangular custom `QWidget`s (e.g. circle-shaped buttons), can I overlap them?

It seems there is no way to let Qt know which parts of the widgets are opaque, so mouse event are delivered to the correct `QWidget` (It looks like Qt assumes each widget occupies its bounding rectangle).

Should I turn these widgets into `QGraphicsItem`s instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give QWidgets a mask if you want them to be non-rectangular.  This should work, but it's not always straightforward to create the mask region.  QGraphicsItem certainly makes handling non-rectangular shapes much easier.

Comment: Using QWidget masks can drastically affect performances, so if you 'know' programmatic-ally the shape of your widget (circle ...) it could be a good idea to re-implement event handler and pass events to parent widget when you are out of the shape.